# Solr search engine and nlu

Tags: search, solr, speech-recognition, nlu

I want to build a query using solr based on nlu semantic which is based on entities. How can get benefit from NLU results even some entities don't exists as fields in solr database ? I tried to filter results and I got wrong results because when filtering, it's mandatory to filter by fields that exists in solr database.
Example of solr fields:

```
{ "id":"07Ce2HEBB-PtfltbxUlv", "nom":["Microsoft Surface Pro 4 Type Cover with Fingerprint ID"], "categorie":["Accessoires pour ordinateurs"], "image":["No image"], "marque":["Microsoft"], "version":1665642569640443904}
```

and this is an example of NLU output:

```
{
  "intent": {
    "name": "Haut-parleurs",
    "confidence": 0.9998957514762878
  },
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "type",
      "start": 13,
      "end": 21,
      "extractor": "DIETClassifier",
      "value": "sans fil"
    },
    {
      "entity": "marque",
      "start": 22,
      "end": 26,
      "extractor": "DIETClassifier",
      "value": "Sony"
    },
    {
      "entity": "model",
      "start": 27,
      "end": 37,
      "extractor": "DIETClassifier",
      "value": "SRSHG1/BLK"
    },
    {
      "entity": "couleur",
      "start": 47,
      "end": 51,
      "extractor": "DIETClassifier",
      "value": "noir",
      "processors": [
        "EntitySynonymMapper"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "intent_ranking": [
    {
      "name": "Haut-parleurs",
      "confidence": 0.9998957514762878
    },
    {
      "name": "greet",
      "confidence": 9.423414303455502e-05
    },
    {
      "name": "Casques Bluetooth",
      "confidence": 9.48187880567275e-06
    },
    {
      "name": "Boitier lecteur multimedia",
      "confidence": 4.859907676291186e-07
    },
    {
      "name": "Bonbons",
      "confidence": 1.837529062242993e-08
    }
  ],
  "response_selector": {
    "default": {
      "response": {
        "name": null,
        "confidence": 0.0
      },
      "ranking": [],
      "full_retrieval_intent": null
    }
  },
  "text": "Haut-parleur sans fil Sony SRSHG1/BLK Hi-Res - Noir anthracite"
}
```

"text": "Haut-parleur sans fil Sony SRSHG1/BLK Hi-Res - Noir anthracite": represent the client query who search for 'haut-parleur', 'sans fil', 'sony','SRSHG1/BLK', and of color 'noir'.
this is what I am trying:

```
folder_path = 'D:/nlu/'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.json')):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        json_files = json.load(f)
        text=json_files['text']
    for i in variable:
        if(("marque" in entities) and ("categorie" in entities) and ("nom" in entities) and ("image" in entities)):
            if(i['entity']=="marque"):
                results=solr.search(q="*:*",fq=["marque:"+i['value']])
                docs=pd.DataFrame(results.docs)
                print(docs)
            elif(i["entity"]=="nom"):
                results=solr.search(q="*:*",fq=["nom:"+i['value']])
                docs=pd.DataFrame(results.docs)
                print(docs)
            elif(i["entity"]=="categorie"):
                results=solr.search(q="*:*",fq=["categorie:"+i['value']])
                docs=pd.DataFrame(results.docs)
                print(docs)
            elif(i["entity"]=="image"):
                results=solr.search(q="*:*",fq=["image:"+i['value']])
                docs=pd.DataFrame(results.docs)
                print(docs)
            else:
                print("*******")
        elif(("marque" in entities) or ("categorie" in entities) or ("nom" in entities)):
            if(i['entity']=="marque" and i['entity']!="nom" and i['entity']!="categorie" and i['entity']!="image"):
                results=solr.search(q=["marque:"+i['value']])
                docs=pd.DataFrame(results.docs)
                print(docs)
            elif(i["entity"]=="nom" and i['entity']!="marque" and i['entity']!="categorie" and i['entity']!="image"):
                results=solr.search(q=["nom:"+i['value']])
                docs=pd.DataFrame(results.docs)
                print(docs)
            elif(i["entity"]=="categorie" and i['entity']!="nom" and i['entity']!="marque" and i['entity']!="image"):
                results=solr.search(q=["categorie:"+i['value']])
                docs=pd.DataFrame(results.docs)
                print(docs)
            elif(i["entity"]=="image" and i['entity']!="nom" and i['entity']!="categorie" and i['entity']!="marque"):
                results=solr.search(q=["image:"+i['value']])
                docs=pd.DataFrame(results.docs)
                print(docs)
            else:
                results=solr.search(q="_text_:"+json_files['text'])
                docs=pd.DataFrame(results.docs)
                docs=pd.DataFrame(results.docs)
                print(docs)
        else:
            results=solr.search(q="_text_:"+json_files['text'])
            docs=pd.DataFrame(results.docs)
            docs=pd.DataFrame(results.docs)
            print(docs)
```

I want to filter search by fields that is not stored or indexed in solr database using pysolr 
the output is:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
                     id                                                nom  \
0  4bCe2HEBB-PtfltbxUlv  [Haut-parleur sans fil Sony SRSHG1/BLK Hi-Res ...   
1  47Ce2HEBB-PtfltbxUlv  [Mini-cassettes vidÃ©o numÃ©riques Sony - DVC ...   
2  5LCe2HEBB-PtfltbxUlv                    [Haut-parleur sans fil SRS-ZR7]   
3  8LCe2HEBB-PtfltbxUlv  [Facade autoradio CD marin Sony MEXM100BT 160W...   
4  8bCe2HEBB-PtfltbxUlv  [Haut-parleur portable sans fil Sony SRSXB30/B...   
5  8rCe2HEBB-PtfltbxUlv  [Mini-systÃƒÂ¨me LBT-GPX555 de Sony avec Bluet...   
6  2rCe2HEBB-Ptfltb3Gnu       [Sony Nh-Aa-B4gn Rechargeable Ni-MH Battery]   
7  3rCe2HEBB-PtfltbwkXR              [Sony HT-GT1 2.1 Home Theatre System]   

                                   categorie  \
0     [haut-parleurs Bluetooth et  sans fil]   
1               [Accessoires appareil photo]   
2     [haut-parleurs Bluetooth et  sans fil]   
3  [Accessoires Ã©lectroniques pour voiture]   
4     [haut-parleurs Bluetooth et  sans fil]   
5              [Accessoires audio et vidÃ©o]   
6                    [Cameras & Accessories]   
7                       [Home Entertainment]   

                                               image  marque  \
0                                         [No image]  [Sony]   
1                                         [No image]  [Sony]   
2                                         [No image]  [Sony]   
3                                         [No image]  [Sony]   
4                                         [No image]  [Sony]   
5                                         [No image]  [Sony]   
6  [http://img6a.flixcart.com/image/rechargeable-...  [Sony]   
7  [http://img6a.flixcart.com/image/home-theatre-...  [Sony]   

             _version_  
0  1665642569914122240  
1  1665642569924608000  
2  1665642569927753728  
3  1665642569950822400  
4  1665642569950822401  
5  1665642569953968128  
6  1665642572737937420  
7  1665642573811679246  
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
​
```

but it seems wrong because the client want exactly: "Haut-parleur sans fil Sony SRSHG1/BLK Hi-Res - Noir anthracite" described in NLU output

Comment: What does a query that you send to Solr look like? What are you trying to filter by? Please add the example as text to your post and not as an image - it's hard to make sense of images for those who use screen readers, it's not really possible to search for its content later, makes it impossible to copy and paste to experiment with, and it may require people to switch back and forth between different tabs to keep track of all the details in your question.

Comment: Ok,I edited my question,above is what I tried and the result that I got

Comment: and here is my fields: {
        "id":"07Ce2HEBB-PtfltbxUlv",
        "nom":["Microsoft Surface Pro 4 Type Cover with Fingerprint ID"],
        "categorie":["Accessoires pour ordinateurs"],
        "image":["No image"],
        "marque":["Microsoft"],
        "_version_":1665642569640443904},
      {

Comment: Please add them properly formatted to your question - don't hide them away in the comments :-)

Comment: Ok, I did it ,any help pls?